# Generating list of numbers in Teradata Sql Asst

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to generate a list like -3, -4, -5, -6, -7 in Teradata Sql asst. Is there any direct way to do it. Sample attached here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bR70.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata, there isn't a built-in function for generating a sequence of numbers. However, you can achieve this by using a recursive cte as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE nums AS
(
  SELECT -7 AS n FROM DBC.DBCInfoV WHERE InfoKey='Version' -- or from any table you already have
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM nums WHERE n < -3
)
SELECT * 
FROM nums
ORDER BY n DESC
```

Comment: This won't run in teradata.  The union requires an actual table.  Easy enough to get around with a volatile table though.

Comment: Or just add any FROM / WHERE clause to the initial SELECT that returns a single row. For example `FROM DBC.DBCInfoV WHERE InfoKey='Version'`

Comment: I have edited my answer, Thank you all For the help